# Show one more model in my details view in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have three tables from which I created an entity model. Below is the model.
[image]

I need help to combine all the three models in one view. For example I want to show lastName, initials form cpd_recipinets and TestNo from cpd_quiz and paid in cpd_certificates in one view.

When I click edit, I this items are also available for editing. Though the tables seem not related there are can actually be referenced though there is orphaned values.
Below is code for detail view:

```
 @model Test.Models.cpd_recipients

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>cpd_recipients</legend>

    <div class="display-label">OpNo</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OpNo)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">LastName</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Initials</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Initials)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Title</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>


    <div class="display-label">cpd_password</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.cpd_password)
    </div>
</fieldset>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=Model.ID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: are you using the tables to be your model ? or have you created separate view models, please share the view models if any

Comment: @yasser Yes I am using table as model. This a database first entity framework development approach. I will edit the post to include some of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create a `ViewModel` - a class that contains only the data that you View requires, from the various disparate Models in your data model.

So your details viewmodel would contain (lastName, initials, TestNo, paid).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

Comment: Thanks Podiluska. I have read the link you provided and had tried that approach. What I dont understand about this class is should it be like the one where I do the code first approach? I am lost with this approach.

Comment: @Sithelo This may help http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/04/13/asp-net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc 3 and I have made a viewmodel but how do I link it with my existing classes/model? Otherwise with this viewmodel it saying table viewmodel doesnot exist.

Comment: You populate the ViewModel in the controller from the Models.

Comment: I am sorry to say I am not following. I created a contoller with empty read/write actions.  Then I added a view and choose my new viewmodel as amodel class. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, but your controller could equally be based on the EF model.